# Single-sign-on using Windows AD , with no need to tweak client browser setting

Tags: php, single-sign-on

I have successfully setup NTLM Authentication (Active Directory) on Apache (Linux). However I still get a login credentials pop-up. That can be only resolved if I tweak the client browser setting i.e Firefox and Internet explorer setting . For an example, in the case of Internet Explorer I would need to set the Security-->Local Intranet-->Add the URL into trusted website.
With this using a php script I able to see the REMOTE_USER variable.

```
The REMOTE_USER is <?php echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]; ?><br>
The HTTP_AUTH_USER is <?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_AUTH_USER"]; ?><br>
The PHP_AUTH_USER is <?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]; ?><br>
```

Now will there be any chance I can setup single sign on without the need to tweak client browser settings? and of course avoiding login credentials. Thanks.

Comment: Probably not. This would be one that I am *most* glad to be corrected on, but I sadly doubt that it would be that user-friendly. Having said that, you could potentially force the user to add to trusted by checking the credentials and limiting use/options if they do not add to trusted sites.

Comment: For firefox it's not possible, but for IE you can set a group policy to add the server to trusted sites.